# ActiveRecord count and group by statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Part` object which has `Supplier` and part has field `supplier_id`.

So I have a number of records and I want to determine how many parts came from how many suppliers. So let's say I have parts arranged like this. Number of parts = 100

```
25 came from supplier_id => 3
25 came from supplier_id => 1
50 came from supplier_id => 5
```

So here is how I made my query :

```
Part.where(:order_id => 30146).select('count(id) as count, supplier_id').group('supplier_id').order('count DESC')
```

And it seems to produce the correct query as well :

```
SELECT count(id) as count, supplier_id FROM "parts" WHERE "parts"."order_id" = 30146 AND ("parts"."deleted_at" IS NULL) GROUP BY supplier_id ORDER BY count DESC
```

But my result is not like I intended to :

```
[#<Part supplier_id: 3>, #<Part supplier_id: 1>, #<Part supplier_id: 5>]
```

I get just the supplier ids but not the count. I wanted to get output like this :

```
25 => 3
25 => 1
50 => 5
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show the remaining code which is producing the output you're seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The count method takes a hash which you can supply it to get a hash of ids to counts. For you, it might be something like:

```
Part.where(order_id: 123).count(group: "supplier_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the keyword **count** is reserved in SQL-Query, try countA for example.

```
SELECT count(id) as countA, ...
```